# Deserialize JSON to class with abstract and non-default constructor types of fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, objectmapper

I am working on conversion from JSON using Jackson 2, I work with application code that I cannot interfere into (Tacton Software). In there I have a class like that:

```
 public class Quotation {
        private Reference currency; // This type does not have deafult constructor
        private List<QuotationItem> quotationItems = new ArrayList(); // In this there are abstract fields 
    // Getters, setters and other fields  omitted for clarity 
    }
```

So basically I tried already to extend Quotation class like that:

```
class JSONQuotation extends Quotation{
   @JsonSetter("currency")
    public void notSetCurrency(JSONReference ref){
        this.setCurrency(null);
    }
   @JsonSetter("items")
   @Override
    public void setItems (List<QuotationItem> item){

 }
}
```

So there are two types of annotation I used:

- Ignore setter for field I don't want to deserialize
- Override setter

Anyway I'm still getting errors from ObjectMapper, of course, I had set MixIns

```
  mapper.addMixIn(Quotation.class,JSONQuotation.class);
```

Anybody can help me with this or recommend some other deserializer ?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Posting a stack trace would be good

Comment: Error message :
Can not construct instance of com.tacton.tcsite.entities.Reference: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: Seems to be due to missing constructor for the subclass. Try creating a default constructor for `JSONQuotation` class and then see if the problem persists. Alternatively, if that doesn't solve the issue, try creating a parameterized constructor with annotations for the mapping between class fields and json props,eg `JSONQuotation(@JsonProperty("currency")  Reference currency .....so on for all the variables...)`